# Is Google translate creating broken links on my website

Tags: google-translate

I have inherited development of a website and Google translate was already implemented.

I have made mainly cosmetic changes to the site since taking it over but recently I have seen a lot (3000+) of broken links in Search console.

They follow the patten:
Reffering page + *string* :
domain/page/*some_extra_string_that_does_not_exisst* e.g.

```
/product/hbeab/lib/utils/*common*
/product/100ml-matt-black-glass-bottles-bamboo-atomisers-pack-of-140/*inffast*
/product-tag/5ml-bottle-dripper-insert/*zlib/deflate*
/product-tag/20ml-blue-glass-bottle-2-2/*lib/utils/common*
```

This code can't be seen in the source but only when inspecting source code (chrome) as I believe this is added after page load with javascript.

Google translate code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Code (I believe) is added by the above code:

```
/**
 * @license
 * pako 1.0.6 nodeca/pako
 * Copyright (C) 2014-2017 by Vitaly Puzrin and Andrei Tuputcyn
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * Ported from zlib 1.2.8
 * Copyright (C) 1995-2013 Jean-loup Gailly and Mark Adler
 *
 * This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
 * warranty.  In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
 * arising from the use of this software.
 *
 * Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
 * including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
 * freely, subject to the following restrictions:
 *
 * 1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
 *    claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
 *    in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
 *    appreciated but is not required.
 * 2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
 *    misrepresented as being the original software.
 * 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
 *
 * Jean-loup Gailly        Mark Adler
 * jloup@gzip.org          madler@alumni.caltech.edu
 */
!function(t){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=t();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],t);else{("undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this).pako=t()}}(function(){return function t(e,a,i){function n(s,o){if(!a[s]){if(!e[s]){var l="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!o&&l)return l(s,!0);if(r)return r(s,!0);var h=new Error("Cannot find module '"+s+"'");throw h.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",h}var d=a[s]={exports:{}};e[s][0].call(d.exports,function(t){var a=e[s][1][t];return n(a||t)},d,d.exports,t,e,a,i)}return a[s].exports}for(var r="function"==typeof require&&require,s=0;s<i.length;s++)n(i[s]);return n}({1:[function(t,e,a){"use strict";function i(t){if(!(this instanceof i))return new i(t);this.options=s.assign({level:_,method:c,chunkSize:16384,windowBits:15,memLevel:8,strategy:u,to:""},t||{});var e=this.options;e.raw&&e.windowBits>0?e.windowBits=-e.windowBits:e.gzip&&e.windowBits>0&&e.windowBits<16&&(e.windowBits+=16),this.err=0,this.msg="",this.ended=!1,this.chunks=[],this.strm=new h,this.strm.avail_out=0;var a=r.deflateInit2(this.strm,e.level,e.method,e.windowBits,e.memLevel,e.strategy);if(a!==f)throw new Error(l[a]);if(e.header&&r.deflateSetHeader(this.strm,e.header),e.dictionary){var n;if(n="string"==typeof e.dictionary?o.string2buf(e.dictionary):"[object ArrayBuffer]"===d.call(e.dictionary)?new Uint8Array(e.dictionary):e.dictionary,(a=r.deflateSetDictionary(this.strm,n))!==f)throw new Error(l[a]);this._dict_set=!0}}function n(t,e){var a=new i(e);if(a.push(t,!0),a.err)throw a.msg||l[a.err];return a.result}var r=t("./zlib/deflate"),s=t("./utils/common"),o=t("./utils/strings"),l=t("./zlib/messages"),h=t("./zlib/zstream"),d=Object.prototype.toString,f=0,_=-1,u=0,c=8;i.prototype.push=function(t,e){var a,i,n=this.strm,l=this.options.chunkSize;if(this.ended)return!1;i=e===~~e?e:!0===e?4:0,"string"==typeof t?n.input=o.string2buf(t):"[object ArrayBuffer]"===d.call(t)?n.input=new Uint8Array(t):n.input=t,n.next_in=0,n.avail_in=n.input.length;do{if(0===n.avail_out&&(n.output=new s.Buf8(l),n.next_out=0,n.avail_out=l),1!==(a=r.deflate(n,i))&&a!==f)return this.onEnd(a),this.ended=!0,!1;0!==n.avail_out&&(0!==n.avail_in||4!==i&&2!==i)||("string"===this.options.to?this.onData(o.buf2binstring(s.shrinkBuf(n.output,n.next_out))):this.onData(s.shrinkBuf(n.output,n.next_out)))}while((n.avail_in>0||0===n.avail_out)&&1!==a);return 4===i?(a=r.deflateEnd(this.strm),this.onEnd(a),this.ended=!0,a===f):2!==i||(this.onEnd(f),n.avail_out=0,!0)},i.prototype.onData=function(t){this.chunks.push(t)},i.prototype.onEnd=function(t){t===f&&("string"===this.options.to?this.result=this.chunks.join(""):this.result=s.flattenChunks(this.chunks)),this.chunks=[],this.err=t,this.msg=this.strm.msg},a.Deflate=i,a.deflate=n,a.deflateRaw=function(t,e){return e=e||{},e.raw=!0,n(t,e)},a.gzip=function(t,e){return e=e||{},e.gzip=!0,n(t,e)}},{"./utils/common":3,"./utils/strings":4,"./zlib/deflate":8,"./zlib/messages":13,"./zlib/zstream":15}],2:[function(t,e,a){"use strict";function i(t){if(!(this instanceof i))return new i(t);this.options=s.assign({chunkSize:16384,windowBits:0,to:""},t||{});var e=this.options;e.raw&&e.windowBits>=0&&e.windowBits<16&&(e.windowBits=-e.windowBits,0===e.windowBits&&(e.windowBits=-15)),!(e.windowBits>=0&&e.windowBits<16)||t&&t.windowBits||(e.windowBits+=32),e.windowBits>15&&e.windowBits<48&&0==(15&e.windowBits)&&(e.windowBits|=15),this.err=0,this.msg="",this.ended=!1,this.chunks=[],this.strm=new d,this.strm.avail_out=0;var a=r.inflateInit2(this.strm,e.windowBits);if(a!==l.Z_OK)throw new Error(h[a]);this.header=new f,r.inflateGetHeader(this.strm,this.header)}function n(t,e){var a=new i(e);if(a.push(t,!0),a.err)throw a.msg||h[a.err];return a.result}var r=t("./zlib/inflate"),s=t("./utils/common"),o=t("./utils/strings"),l=t("./zlib/constants"),h=t("./zlib/messages"),d=t("./zlib/zstream"),f=t("./zlib/gzheader"),_=Object.prototype.toString;i.prototype.push=function(t,e){var a,i,n,h,d,f,u=this.strm,c=this.options.chunkSize,b=this.options.dictionary,g=!1;if(this.ended)return!1;i=e===~~e?e:!0===e?l.Z_FINISH:l.Z_NO_FLUSH,"string"==typeof t?u.input=o.binstring2buf(t):"[object ArrayBuffer]"===_.call(t)?u.input=new Uint8Array(t):u.input=t,u.next_in=0,u.avail_in=u.input.length;do{if(0===u.avail_out&&(u.output=new s.Buf8(c),u.next_out=0,u.avail_out=c),(a=r.inflate(u,l.Z_NO_FLUSH))===l.Z_NEED_DICT&&b&&(f="string"==typeof b?o.string2buf(b):"[object ArrayBuffer]"===_.call(b)?new Uint8Array(b):b,a=r.inflateSetDictionary(this.strm,f)),a===l.Z_BUF_ERROR&&!0===g&&(a=l.Z_OK,g=!1),a!==l.Z_STREAM_END&&a!==l.Z_OK)return this.onEnd(a),this.ended=!0,!1;u.next_out&&(0!==u.avail_out&&a!==l.Z_STREAM_END&&(0!==u.avail_in||i!==l.Z_FINISH&&i!==l.Z_SYNC_FLUSH)||("string"===this.options.to?(n=o.utf8border(u.output,u.next_out),h=u.next_out-n,d=o.buf2string(u.output,n),u.next_out=h,u.avail_out=c-h,h&&s.arraySet(u.output,u.output,n,h,0),this.onData(d)):this.onData(s.shrinkBuf(u.output,u.next_out)))),0===u.avail_in&&0===u.avail_out&&(g=!0)}while((u.avail_in>0||0===u.avail_out)&&a!==l.Z_STREAM_END);return a===l.Z_STREAM_END&&(i=l.Z_FINISH),i===l.Z_FINISH?(a=r.inflateEnd(this.strm),this.onEnd(a),this.ended=!0,a===l.Z_OK):i!==l.Z_SYNC_FLUSH||(this.onEnd(l.Z_OK),u.avail_out=0,!0)},i.prototype.onData=function(t){this.chunks.push(t)},i.prototype.onEnd=function(t){t===l.Z_OK&&("string"===this.options.to?this.result=this.chunks.join(""):this.result=s.flattenChunks(this.chunks)),this.chunks=[],this.err=t,this.msg=this.strm.msg},a.Inflate=i,a.inflate=n,a.inflateRaw=function(t,e){return e=e||{},e.raw=!0,n(t,e)},a.ungzip=n},{"./utils/common":3,"./utils/strings":4,"./zlib/constants":6,"./zlib/gzheader":9,"./zlib/inflate":11,"./zlib/messages":13,"./zlib/zstream":15}],3:[function(t,e,a){"use strict";function i(t,e){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,e)}var n="undefined"!=typeof Uint8Array&&"undefined"!=typeof Uint16Array&&"undefined"!=typeof Int32Array;a.assign=function(t){for(var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);e.length;){var a=e.shift();if(a){if("object"!=typeof a)throw new TypeError(a+"must be non-object");for(var n in a)i(a,n)&&(t[n]=a[n])}}return t},a.shrinkBuf=function(t,e){return t.length===e?t:t.subarray?t.subarray(0,e):(t.length=e,t)};var r={arraySet:function(t,e,a,i,n){if(e.subarray&&t.subarray)t.set(e.subarray(a,a+i),n);else for(var r=0;r<i;r++)t[n+r]=e[a+r]},flattenChunks:function(t){var e,a,i,n,r,s;for(i=0,e=0,a=t.length;e<a;e++)i+=t[e].length;for(s=new Uint8Array(i),n=0,e=0,a=t.length;e<a;e++)r=t[e],s.set(r,n),n+=r.length;return s}},s={arraySet:function(t,e,a,i,n){for(var r=0;r<i;r++)t[n+r]=e[a+r]},flattenChunks:function(t){return[].concat.apply([],t)}};a.setTyped=function(t){t?(a.Buf8=Uint8Array,a.Buf16=Uint16Array,a.Buf32=Int32Array,a.assign(a,r)):(a.Buf8=Array,a.Buf16=Array,a.Buf32=Array,a.assign(a,s))},a.setTyped(n)},{}],4:[function(t,e,a){"use strict";function i(t,e){if(e<65537&&(t.subarray&&s||!t.subarray&&r))return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,n.shrinkBuf(t,e));for(var a="",i=0;i<e;i++)a+=String.fromCharCode(t[i]);return a}var n=t("./common"),r=!0,s=!0;try{String.fromCharCode.apply(null,[0])}catch(t){r=!1}try{String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(1))}catch(t){s=!1}for(var o=new n.Buf8(256),l=0;l<256;l++)o[l]=l>=252?6:l>=248?5:l>=240?4:l>=224?3:l>=192?2:1;o[254]=o[254]=1,a.string2buf=function(t){var e,a,i,r,s,o=t.length,l=0;for(r=0;r<o;r++)55296==(64512&(a=t.charCodeAt(r)))&&r+1<o&&56320==(64512&(i=t.charCodeAt(r+1)))&&(a=65536+(a-55296<<10)+(i-56320),r++),l+=a<128?1:a<2048?2:a<65536?3:4;for(e=new n.Buf8(l),s=0,r=0;s<l;r++)55296==(64512&(a=t.charCodeAt(r)))&&r+1<o&&56320==(64512&(i=t.charCodeAt(r+1)))&&(a=65536+(a-55296<<10)+(i-56320),r++…
```

Removing the google translate code removes the pako code but as search console can take days/weeks to re-index I cant tell if this is 100% the cause of the 404 links. However looking at the pako code I can see references to the erroneous link strings.